# What is the hidden achievement in 10,000,000?

Tags: achievements, 10000000

Steam says I have 9 of the 14 achievements in *10,000,000*, but only shows me 4 of the remaining achievements and indicates that there is one it is not showing me. What is the hidden achievement and how do I get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You [currently miss](http://steamcommunity.com/id/murgatroid99/stats/227580) the **Freedom** achievement, that you would get for "finishing" the game by getting 10,000,000 points in a round, and gaining your freedom by entering the door on the top right. This is the only achievement which is hidden until you get it.

You can see the [complete list of achievements](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/227580/achievements) to compare.

Comment: Just to clarify, the requirement for getting this achievement is getting 10,000,000 points?

Comment: _And_ leave the dungeon via the door to the top right. Only then the achievement is unlocked.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - since your question was only about what was missing, I left out the details on how to actually get the achievement, to avoid potential spoilers :)

Comment: I can understand that. I edited it in because I did specifically ask "how do I get it?" and that was really what I wanted to know.